# Setting up php project with composer and phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I am trying to set up a new php project. Since I am new to phpunit and composer I am struggeling with the project setup.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- TestProject
-- src
--- Controller
----- Foo.php
--- index.php
-- tests
--- Controller
----- FooTest.php
-- vendor
-- composer.json
-- phpunit.xml
```

My composer file:

```
"require": {
   "php": ">=5.4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
   "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.*"
},
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "TestProject\\": "src/"
   }
},
"autoload-dev": {
   "psr-4": {
       "TestProject\\Tests\\": "tests/"
   }
}
```

My phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="TestProject Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Foo.php

```
namespace TestProject\Controller;

class Foo
{
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

FooTest.php

```
namespace TestProject\Tests\Controller;

class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCanBeNegated()
    {
        // Arrange
        $a = new Foo(1);

        // Act
        $b = $a->getAmount();

        // Assert
        $this->assertEquals(1, $b->getAmount());
    }
}
```

But now I am not sure what I am missing to get `./vendor/bin/phpunit .` running. Currently it gives me an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.
```

Comment: Are you adding Composer's `autoload.php` in your project?  If not, `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: I added this `bootstrap="./tests/start.php"` to the `phpunit.xml`. It contains `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`. That should be enough?

Comment: Composer's `autoload.php` is typically loaded at the root of your project (not in `phpunit.xml`).  Take a look at Laravel, Drupal, and other popular PHP projects.

Comment: Do you refer to `PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest` somewhere in your code? You can run `phpunit` with the `-v` option to see a stack trace of the error.

Comment: I found the mistake, I ran the command `./vendor/bin/phpunit . ` in the `TestProject` folder. So phpunit ran over the full project and not only over the files in `./src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a backslash before `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` to load the class from root namespace:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

Comment: If I do that, I get `Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.`

Comment: It is another problem. Add autoload to phpunit.xml: `<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" `

Comment: I added `<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php">` this to the phpunit.xml. The `bootstrap.php` file contains: `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`